# How to get value of button in append(),where classes of many buttons are same

Tags: jquery, append

When loop execute it generate many buttons.How I get the value of clicked button in append().Because I also want to send value of button through ajax.
Correct the error or make it right.

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("form").submit(function(evt){  
        evt.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
       formData.append( 'aabb',$(".uu").click(function(){attr('value')}) );
       $.ajax({
       url: 'pin_insert.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       processData: false,
       success: function (response) {
         $(".text").html(response);
       }
   });
         return false;
 });
        });

     </script>`

    <?php
 echo '<form id ="aa" method="post">';
       echo '<input id="csv" name="csv" type="file" />';
echo '</form>';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_1))
            {
                $pin=$row['board_name'];
                echo'<div>';
                echo $pin;
                echo "...............";
                echo '<button  type="submit" form="aa" class="uu" name="aabb" value='.$pin.'>Save</button>';
                echo '</div>';  
        }
?>
```

Comment: what code you had written for getting value of appended button

Comment: formData.append( 'aabb',$(".uu").click(function(){attr('value')}) );

Comment: but it contains all buttons which having class uu

Comment: can you explain a little what `formData.append( 'aabb',$(".uu").click(function(){attr('value')}) );` does, where did you get this code?

Comment: Give me the correct code for this

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
      function getformsubmit(element){
      var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);
       formData.append( 'aabb',$(element).val());
       $.ajax({
       url: 'pin_insert.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       processData: false,
       success: function (response) {
         $(".text").html(response);
       }
   });
         return false;

    }

     </script>`

    <?php
 echo '<form id ="aa" method="post">';
       echo '<input id="csv" name="csv" type="file" />';
echo '</form>';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_1))
            {
                $pin=$row['board_name'];
                echo'<div>';
                echo $pin;
                echo "...............";
                echo '<button  type="button" form="aa" class="uu" name="aabb" onclick="getformsubmit(this)" value='.$pin.'>Save</button>';
                echo '</div>';  
        }
?>
```

Comment: instead of form submit add click events on buttons